# how to unset http_proxy in ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

In most ansible example, it is to set environment like setting http_proxy below, see http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_environment.html

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - apt: name=cobbler state=installed
    environment:
      http_proxy: http://proxy.example.com:8080
```

In my case, I need this `http_proxy` in system shell, while I want to disable this in playbook, how can I achieve this ?

If I work in shell, I can use `unset http_proxy`

Comment: Have you tried setting that variable to empty?

Comment: yes, it doesn't work. it likes 'set http_proxy=""'

Comment: @LarryCai, did you find a solution ? I am facing the same situation, there was a proxy on my corp network for years and now, it has been removed but I am unable to make this change in my playbook.

Comment: I tried `none` as the value in yaml (which is `None` in Python) in the hope that it would do the trick. But it didn't.

Answer (score 6):

You could temporarily disable the proxy for the host(s) or URL you wanted to talk to, e.g.

```
environment:
  no_proxy: 192.168.1.2,www.google.com
```

Answer (score -1):

Your play will do just that: The environment will only be set for that task, and any subsequent task will not have the variable set.

Try for example:

```
- hosts: all

  tasks:
  - apt: name=cobbler state=installed
    environment:
      http_proxy: http://proxy.example.com:8080

  - shell: "echo $http_proxy"
```

The shell task will return: `"stdout": ""`

Comment: thx, but I want to disable the system http_proxy in playbook.